# Changing a (full pathname) line using sed `s` operation

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.6`

I've tried the following command line:

```
sed -i -e 's/.#!/usr/bin/python.*/#!/usr/bin/python2.6/' /usr/bin/yum
```

...which returns the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

I can't find a good answer anywhere on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because `sed` interprets `s/.#!/usr/b` as your first `s`earch & replace command, and `b` isn't a valid flag for the command.
Indeed, the syntax of these commands is `s<delimiter><search pattern><delimiter><replace><delimiter><flags>`, where the most widely used `<delimiter>` is `/`.

You could escape the `/` in your search pattern and replace string so they aren't interpreted as the delimiter, however since you've got a lot of them I would suggest using another delimiter.

For example, using `+` as a delimiter your `sed` command would become `sed -i -e 's+.#!/usr/bin/python.*+#!/usr/bin/python2.6+'`.

As a side-note, the first `.` in your command is probably a mistake as the shebang should be written directly at the beginning of the files it appears in.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your line is first line from your file. With GNU sed:

```
sed '1s/python$/&2.6/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: It won't do if the first line ends with "python3".  OTOH, if we know it ends with "python$": `sed '1s/$/2.6/'`

Comment: I don't want to change `python3` or change `bash` to `bash2.6`.

Comment: 1. the OP uses '...python.*' as the end of the target, therefore 'python$' would miss 'python3', etc.  2.  Re 'bash': "if we know it ends with 'python$'".

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee that the first line of a file, that ends with `python`, is a shebang.